# What's the Ideal Number of Variations in an A/B Test?

Tags: ab-testing, abtest

We are planning to test 27 buttons in our site to know which one will give the highest conversion rate. I am not sure if this too many variations will give us accurate result. Does anyone know what is the ideal number of variations to produce accurate result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General idea is 100 conversions per butto fo 2700 conversion...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We ended up dividing them into 3, so running only 9 variations + the control, a total of 10 variations at a time.